# How do I compress a .png with Imagick in PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm converting .jpg and .gif images to `.png` using PHP's Imagick library.

I've successfully converted these images to .png using this:

```
$image = new Imagick( $file_path );
$image->setImageFormat( 'png' );
$image->writeImage( $file_path );
```

However, I have been unable to compress the .pngs or control their final size at all.  I've tried using the following line before `$image->setImageFormat()` and a few other variations with no success:

```
$img->setImageCompressionQuality( 95 );
```

If `.png` compression with Imagick is lacking, then what other utilities should I use to compress these files?

This [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png) may help.

Comment: The manual entry you linked mentions pngcrush and OptiPng.  Probably your best bet if you really need to bring file size down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I installed [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) and it works fine.

After a lengthy battle, I was unable to get IMagick to compress png's properly.

Comment: I haven't tested this in a long time, so Imagick may be better with PNGs now.  This answer was from December, 2011.